# Twig for loop can't find record in MySQL database

Tags: symfony, twig

My for loop doesnt seem to be able to find any records in my database.

My loop:

```
            {% for school in scholen %}
                <li>{{ scholen.naam|e }}</li>
            {% else %}
                <li>no user found</li>
            {% endfor %}
```

[My result.](https://gyazo.com/68cd71f1877883ee2187dabed0159469)

If I remove the else it's just 'empty' underneath "Scholen"

This is my controller

```
namespace App\Controller;


use App\Entity\School;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class SchoolController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route ("/scholen", name="scholen")
     * Method ({"GET", "POST"})
     */

    public function schoolgegevens()
    {
        $scholen = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(School::class);


        return $this->render("security/school.html.twig", ["scholen" => $scholen]);
    }

}
```

[My database table "Scholen".](https://gyazo.com/2c33e88aa9444b472d7ff297d98a9a69)

Comment: You're just fetching a repository, not the records. You should issue a `find` to actually fetch data, e.g. `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(School::class)->find()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code :

```
        $scholen = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(School::class);
```

`$scholen` contains your repository, not your data. You must do something like

```
    public function schoolgegevens(SchoolRepository $schoolRepository)
    {
        $scholen = $schoolRepository->findAll();

        return $this->render("security/school.html.twig", ["scholen" => $scholen]);
    }
```

Comment: Ah this worked! Thank you very much. The problem was indeed `$scholen`.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time, try dump($something); You will see exactly the content of $something ;).